# Is TraceProcessor Thread Safe?

Tags: etw, .net-traceprocessing

When I try to parse several ETL files in parallel via

```
 using (ITraceProcessor processor = TraceProcessor.Create(myEtlFile, new TraceProcessorSettings
 {
   AllowLostEvents = true,
 }))
```

I get this exception

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.InvalidComObjectException: COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used. The COM object was released while it was still in use on another thread.
Stack Trace: 
  InterfaceMarshaler.ConvertToManaged(IntPtr pUnk, IntPtr itfMT, IntPtr classMT, Int32 flags)
  AddInManagerAdapter.Create(String toolkitPath)
  ToolkitTraceProcessingEngine.Create(String path, ITraceProcessorSettings settings, ITraceProcessorSettings & effectiveSettings)
  TraceProcessor.Create(String path, ITraceProcessorSettings settings)
```

Is this a bug or a "known" limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known limitation. Given how the underlying native code interaction works, only one trace processor can be created at a time, unfortunately.

In general, TraceProcessor only supports single-threaded access, even for static methods. Some consumers have found places where multi-threaded code can work, but it's not tested/guaranteed - we generally haven't added locks or done anything to enable safe concurrent access.

Comment: Adding to that: the current best guidance is to create separate processes for each TraceProcessor. I.e. trace processing in parallel is possible, but not within a process.

Comment: Thanks! Then I will try the multiprocess approach.